# Trigger Jenkins with Puppet

Tags: jenkins, puppet

Recently our organization decided to move from using Maven/Cargo-plugin to deploy our applications to using Puppet. We still have all of our builds and test jobs in Jenkins. So what I'm trying to figure out is how do I trigger a specific Jenkins job based on a specific line being changed in a puppet manifest? We are using a manifest that has all of our deployed components and their versions. If I change the version of one of the components, I want a specific test job to be triggered based on which component was changed. And eventually I will want to rollback the puppet change if the test fails. Has anyone done something related?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it for your specific use case, but for a "pull" scenario where you want to monitor the contents of the Puppet manifest for changes, the [Jenkins FSTrigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FSTrigger+Plugin) should work for you as long as your Jenkins job can access the Puppet manifest file.  You can set it up to look for changes in the entire file content, or just in a particular part of the contents.

If you want a "push" scenario to trigger a build as soon as the Puppet manifest is changed, you could write a script that runs after the changes are saved, checks which components have been changed, and triggers a build via the [Jenkins CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was hoping that we could do a push rather than a pull. Once the puppet files change, we will need to trigger Puppet to apply the changes and only when they are complete will we be able run our tests.

But again, thank you for the link, I will take a look at it.

Comment: Edited my answer based on your comment.